# How to sort stacked bar charts in Oracle Apex 22?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a stacked bar chart that shows the assigned CPUs (OnlineVirtualCPUs) and actual physical CPU (pc) usage of a host. The goal is to easily differentiate between the total CPUs and the actual CPU usage. However, I am only able to order the graph by the total value, not the physical CPU value.

Context:
I am using Oracle Apex 22.
The data used for the chart includes assigned CPUs and actual physical CPU usage for each host.

Issue:
Order by doesnt seem to be working when working with two charts/series.
The "Sort-Order" under the Region attribute Multi-Series Chart Data only allows to sort by label or value. (Value being the total Value, in my case the assigned cpus, but I want to sort by pysical cpus)

[Sorted by Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Iwc.png)

[Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xv7O.png)

Query both series Series:

```
SELECT 
    host AS Host,
    TO_NUMBER(MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'OnlineVirtualCPUs' THEN val END)) AS OnlineVirtualCPUs,
    TO_NUMBER(MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'pc' THEN val END)) AS PC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'OnlineVirtualCPUs' THEN val ELSE 0 END) - MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'pc' THEN val ELSE 0 END) AS Unused_CPUs,
    MAX(TS) AS Timestamp,
    'Host: ' || host || 
    '<br> OnlineVirtualCPUs: ' || TO_CHAR(MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'OnlineVirtualCPUs' THEN val END)) || 
    '<br> Physical CPUs: ' || TO_CHAR(MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'pc' THEN val END), 'FM0.00') || 
    '<br> Unused CPUs: ' || TO_CHAR(MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'OnlineVirtualCPUs' THEN val ELSE 0 END) - MAX(CASE WHEN obj = 'pc' THEN val ELSE 0 END), 'FM0.00') || 
    '<br> Time: ' || MAX(TS) AS Tooltip
FROM table
WHERE (service = 'service1' AND obj = 'OnlineVirtualCPUs') OR (service = 'service2' AND obj = 'pc') AND ts > SYSDATE - 1
GROUP BY host ORDER BY Unused_CPUs DESC;
```

The PhysicalCPUs series uses 'PC' as its Value and the UnusedCpus Series uses 'unused_cpus' as its value.
Both have host as the label, and tooltip for the custom tooltip.

Thank you in advance for your help in resolving this issue!

Comment: Is it as simple as using `ORDER BY pc DESC`?

Comment: Sadly not, order by doesnt seem to be working when using multiple charts.
There is a region attribute called multi series chart data, with an option called "sort order", but you can only sort by value (total value to be precise, see the image above) or by label.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to deactivate "Fill Gaps in Chart Data" under "Multi-Series Chart Data" and add "order by used_cpus;" for my query.